# Generating a list of values from a pandas DataFrame column for a range of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

For a list of daily maximum temperature values from 5 to 27 degrees celsius,  I want to calculate the corresponding maximum ozone concentration, from the following pandas DataFrame:
[image]

I can do this by using the following code, by changing the 5 then 6, 7 etc.

```
df_c=df_b[df_b['Tmax']==5]
df_c.O3max.max()
```

Then I have to copy and paste the output values into an excel spreadsheet. I'm sure there must be a much more pythonic way of doing this, such as by using a list comprehension.  Ideally I would like to generate a list of values from the column 03max. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.Series.map` with another `pd.Series`

```
pd.Series(list_of_temps).map(df_b.set_index('Tmax')['O3max'])
```

You can get a dataframe

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(temps=list_of_temps))
result_df['O3max'] = result_df.temps.map(df_b.set_index('Tmax')['O3max'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another play around and think the following piece of code seems to do the job:

```
df_c=df_b.groupby(['Tmax'])['O3max'].max()
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on whether this is correct